# How to make sure an ansible playbook runs completely

Tags: bash, debian, ansible, dpkg

I am running this ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
   - name : update system
     apt : update_cache=yes    

   - name : install m4
     apt : name=m4 state=present

   - name : install build-essential
     apt : name=build-essential state=present 

   - name : install gcc
     apt : name=gcc state=present

   - name : install gfortran
     apt : name=gfortran state=present

   - name : install libssl-dev
     apt : name=libssl-dev state=present

   - name : install python-software-properties
     apt : name=python-software-properties state=present

   - name : add sage ppa repo
     apt_repository: repo='ppa:aims/sagemath'

   - name : update system
     apt : update_cache=yes

   - name : install dvipng
     apt : name=dvipng state=present

   - name : install sage binary
     apt : name=sagemath-upstream-binary state=present

   - name : invoke create_sagenb script
     command: /usr/bin/screen -d -m sudo /root/databases-and-datamining-iiith/python-scripts/create_sagenb -i -y

   - name : invoke start_sage script
     command: /usr/bin/screen -d -m sudo /root/databases-and-datamining-iiith/python-scripts/start_sage -i -y
```

This playbook fails during task "`install build-essential`" and stops with error asking to run `dpkg --configure -a`. 
How can I make sure that the playbook runs again after facing this error by running the command

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

first and then continue with other tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Ansible in general is idempotent. That means you can simply run your playbook again after resolving the issue without conflicts.

This is not always true. In case you have a more complex play and execute tasks depending on the result of another task, this can break easily and a failed task then would bring you into a state that is not so easy to be fixed with Ansible. But that is not the case with the tasks you provided.

If you want to speed things up and skip all the tasks and/or hosts that did not fail, you can work with `--limit` and/or `--start-at-task`:

When the playbook fails, you might notice Ansible shows a message including a command which will enable you to limit the play to hosts which failed. So if only 1 host failed you do not need to run the playbook on all hosts:

```
ansible-playbook ... --limit @/Users/your-username/name-of-playbook.retry
```

To start at a specific task, you can use `--start-at-task`. So if your playbook failed at the task "install build-essential" you can start again at right this task and skip all previous tasks:

```
ansible-playbook ... --start-at-task="install build-essential"
```

---

On a side note, the apt module is optimized to work with loops. You can speed up your play by combining the tasks into one single apt task:

```
  tasks:
   - name: Install packages that we need for need for apt_repository
     apt: update_cache=yes  
          name={{ item }}
          state=present 
          cache_valid_time=3600
     with_items:
       - python-software-properties
       - python-software-properties-common

   - name: add sage ppa repo
     apt_repository: repo='ppa:aims/sagemath'

   - name: Install packages
     apt: update_cache=yes  
          cache_valid_time=3600
          name={{ item }}
          state=present 
     with_items:
       - m4
       - build-essential
       - gcc
       - gfortran
       - libssl-dev
       - dvipng
       - sagemath-upstream-binary
```